# Vue3 script Setup and TS error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Stuff | undefined'.` workaround

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Using Vue3's script setup syntax and getting a weird ts error when assigning a variable as a prop value.

I have a type definition for `Stuff: 'item' | 'box' | 'area'` and I'm using that PropType my prop `kind` in the **SearchBar** component.

```
const props = defineProps({
  kind: { type: String as PropType<Stuff> },
  placeholder: String,
})
```

However when I fill that prop in on the component with a variable that has the value of `'item'` I get this error:

[image]

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Stuff | undefined'.`

I've seen this sort of error mentioning `string` and `String` before so there's even an error in the casing of string (I know TS uses lowercase and Vue uses Pascalcase).

If anyone has a good workaround or any advice I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Code images are unfortunately not allowed, please edit your question with a snippet of code in some actual text.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and 'edits' (which seem unnecessary honestly).  I added a the props code, but I'm not sure what else you'd like me to do here. The only reason I have the other image is to show the whole error message I'm seeing. Thanks

Comment: I cleaned up a bit of grammar and removed some fluff. Nothing critical but no review is needed and people can focus on the actual things. Feel free to roll them back if it's annoying to you. All good with the other image, of course!

Answer (score 1):

That is a common Ts error. I had the same before. try this:

```js
    const props = defineProps({
      kind: { type: Stuff | undefined },
      placeholder: String,
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I get an error using this syntax though that says `No overload matches this call.`
`Overload 1 of 3, '(props: string[]): Readonly<{ [x: string]: any; }>', gave the following error.` and a few others. Not sure the best way to handle these